# Add tool-tip on fabric.js object

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I would like to draw line object with dynamic tool-tip beside the line by fabric.js.

*The tool-tip content will changed on change line length.

This image give more details about the issue :

[image]

and here the line object script

```js
var line = new fabric.Line(points, {
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'red',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(line);
```

please if any advice or help for how to do this ?
Thanks.